# SQL MIN from different groups

Tags: sql-server

I have this sql query

```
WITH Temp AS(
  SELECT zip.zip_code
 , zip.zip_name
 , place.name, 
   ROUND(CAST((3959 * acos( cos( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(place.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(zip.longitude) - radians(place.longitude) ) 
                    + sin( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * sin( radians(place.latitude)) ) )AS DECIMAL),2) AS distance
 FROM zip JOIN place ON zip.state_code = place.state_code
 WHERE zip.state_code=6 
 AND place.state_code=6
 ORDER BY zip.zip_code
 )
SELECT zip_code
 , zip_name
 , name
 , distance
FROM Temp
WHERE distance <= 5.00;
```

which produces a table (zip code,zip name,name,distance) that lists in order of zip code the zip code(s) that are close to place name by 5 miles and I want to chose the minimum distance for each name(The closest zip code for each name).

I tried this query but it didn't not work it took long time not producing any thing (I think it is not an error but because of the large number of rows) so is there better and quicker way to do this ?

```
WITH Temp AS(
SELECT zip.zip_code
 , zip.zip_name
 , place.name, 
   ROUND(CAST((3959 * acos( cos( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(place.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(zip.longitude) - radians(place.longitude) ) 
                    + sin( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * sin( radians(place.latitude)) ) )AS DECIMAL),2) AS distance
   FROM zip JOIN place ON zip.state_code = place.state_code
   WHERE zip.state_code=6 
    AND place.state_code=6
   ORDER BY zip.zip_code )
 SELECT zip_code
 , zip_name
 , name
 , distance
   FROM Temp
   WHERE distance = (select min(distance) from Temp as f where f.name = Temp.name) 
     AND distance <= 5.00;
```

Comment: MySQL does not support CTEs, so I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `row_number()` instead:

```
WITH Temp AS (
      SELECT zip.zip_code, zip.zip_name, place.name, 
             ROUND(CAST((3959 * acos( cos( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(place.latitude) ) 
                    * cos( radians(zip.longitude) - radians(place.longitude) ) 
                    + sin( radians(zip.latitude) ) 
                    * sin( radians(place.latitude)) ) )AS DECIMAL),2) AS distance
      FROM zip JOIN
           place
           ON zip.state_code = place.state_code
      WHERE zip.state_code = 6 AND place.state_code = 6
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT zip_code, zip_name, name, distance,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY distance) as seqnum
      FROM Temp
      WHERE distance <= 5.00
     ) z
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

As a note, `order by` has no effect in CTEs.